# hide next menu item of horizontal navbar on hover affect

Tags: css

Here is the code

---------------------------CSS----------------------

```
body {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    text-align: left;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: url('../images/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x 0px 30px;
}
.dsply { display: none; }

.logo { background: url(../images/logo.jpg) no-repeat 25px 25px; 
        float:left; 

        width: 175px; 
        height: 150px;
}

.nav-flag-left {  /* background: url(../images/nav-flag-left.png) no-repeat 13px 40px; */
        float:left; 
        margin-top:47px;
        margin-left:0px;
        width: 13px; 
        height: 40px;
} 
#menu {

    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top:47px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS,"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:left;
    float:left; 

    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #DA9AFB; 
    background-color:#F6F9E8; 
/*  background-image: url(../images/logo.jpg);*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 0px;
}


#menu li {
    display:inline;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:auto;
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#7D169D;
    padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu li:hover {
    display:inline;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #FCF;
    padding-top:20px;
/*  background-color:#7D169D;*/
    background-image: url(../images/pinkcloud.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
/*  background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 60px 90px; */
    top:40px;
    height:60px;
    width:90px;
    position:absolute; 
}
.nav-flag-plane {  
        float:left; 
        margin-top:32px;
        margin-left:0px;
        width: 109px; 
        height: 71px;
} 

.nav-menu-cloude {  
        float:left; 
        margin-top:32px;
        margin-left:35px;
        width: 109px; 
        height: 75px;
}
```

using above given css and an image on hover effect.The problem is when mouse over on first menu item other items become shrink and the second item become hide.

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle? A wall of code is not motivating to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: please post your HTML code too... and also don't forget to explain what you want.. CLEARLY..

Comment: i ask the same question again and also share both css and html code.please check it.i think you understand my question.i want to show image on hover effect every thing is working properly but the next menu item going to be hide or shrink.